# PHP require statement not working

Tags: php, require

I have this code:

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require '../src/config/db.php';

$app = new \Slim\App;
$app->get('/hello/{name}', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
    $name = $request->getAttribute('name');
    $response->getBody()->write("Let's get started, $name");

    return $response;
});

// Customer Routes
require '../src/routes/customers.php';

// Calendar Routes
require '../src/routes/calendar.php';


$app->run();
```

The `require '../vendor/autoload.php';` is for Composer.

The browser only displays the last require statement, which is in this case:

```
// Calendar Routes
require '../src/routes/calendar.php';
```

If I want to display, for example, customers.php, then I would need to change the `require` order like this:

```
// Calendar Routes
require '../src/routes/calendar.php';

// Customer Routes
require '../src/routes/customers.php';
```

I would like to be able to display both `require` statemnts and `$app->get('/hello/{name}'` at once, with just typing different http://localhost in the browser.

Comment: There's no reason this wouldn't be including those files.  What's actually *in* those files?  What's the exact response from the server?  (Not what the browser ultimately displays, but the actual HTTP response.)

Comment: The browser should not show any require statements. It should show only your rendered HTML, not your actual PHP code. Make sure the file has a php extension, and that your webserver can process PHP files.

Comment: "with just typing different http://localhost in the browser" What do you mean by that?

Comment: David: in calendar.php and customers.php you can find: `<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;

// Get All Customers
$app->get('/api/calendar', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
echo 'CALENDAR'; });` or 'echo `CUSTOMERS'; });` in customers.php. How can I check HTTP response?

Comment: Matthias Fax: I mean: _http://http://slimapp/api/customers_ where _slimapp_ is configured as _localhost_. The exact response is: _"Page Not Found" "The page you are looking for could not be found. Check the address bar to ensure your URL is spelled correctly. If all else fails, you can visit our home page at the link below."_

Comment: Any chance for help? :)